# Print hex array values

Tags: c, arrays

I'd like that output show me values like this: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...,A,B,C,D,E,F

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 int i;
    unsigned char temp2[32]= {0x00  ,0x11  ,0x22  ,0x33  ,0x44  ,0x55,0x66  ,0x77  ,0x88  ,0x99  ,0xaa  ,0xbb  ,0xcc  ,0xdd  ,0xee  ,0xff};
for(i=0;i<16;i++) {
    printf("%X", temp2[i] & 0xff);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(i)putchar(',');
    printf("%X", temp2[i] & 0x0f);` ?

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the output 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...,A,B,C,D,E,F

You have to read the 4 least significant bits of each value in the array.

Thus, the second argument of printf should be:

temp2[i] & 0xf

Answer (score 0):

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...,A,B,C,D,E,F in Hex should be 0x00, 0x01, 0x02...0x0f, right?

That *temp2* array you have are 0x00, 0x11,0x22...0xff

So with simple math, we know to make 0x11(00010001) become 0x01(000000001), we just need 0x11(00010001) and 0x0f(00001111).

Drop 4 bits on the left.